# Cannot read property 'input' of undefined (reading-onPress)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

[image: error]

Pressable OnPress

```js
<Pressable onPress={() => searchPlaces(route?.params.input)}></Pressable>
```

searchPlaces

```js
const searchPlaces = (place) => {
    if (route.params || !selectedDates) {
      Alert.alert("Invalid Details", "Please Fill the details", [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        { text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') },
      ]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the code + error message, but also a textual description on what the code is supposed to do, and what it currently does, see [mre]. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [Edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error tells you (probably, hard to tell with so little information) that `.params` is undefined when you try to access `route?.params.input` and that you cannot read an `.input` property from `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no property with the name input getting passed from route?. params, try logging it to check if there's any.

You can add a ? to avoid this error.

```
<Pressable onPress={() => searchPlaces(route?.params?.input)}></Pressable>


const searchPlaces = (place) => {
if (route.params || !selectedDates) {
  Alert.alert("Invalid Details", "Please Fill the details", [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    { text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') },
  ]);
}
```